# The subspace generated by $A\cup B$ is contained in the union of subspaces generated by A and B?

Tags: linear-algebra

can you help me with this?

Let V a vetorial space and A and B finite sets of V.

If R is the subspace generated by $A\cup B$ and U and W are the subspaces gerenated by A and B, respectively, then $R\subseteq U\cup W$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? The answer is no (it fact $R$ contains $U\cup W$. but no point giving you full detail if we don't know where you are stuck.

Comment: Actually, I've seen in a list of exercises that this result was valid, so I tried to proof without a success...but now I already found an example that this result does not follow...thanks!